# Strange syntax error using UNION and OFFSET/FETCH

Tags: sql-server, union, fetch, offset, common-table-expression

Why does this query works :

```
WITH SELECTION_FICHE_IMMOVEIL AS 
(
SELECT
        FI.ID_FICHE_IMMOVEIL,
        FI.[ID_THEME_IMMOVEIL ] AS ID_THEME_IMMOVEIL,
        FI.ID_SOUS_THEME_IMMOVEIL,
        FI.IM_DT_CREATION,
        A.ID_ARTICLE,
        A.AR_DT_CREATION,
        CAST(A.AR_TITRE AS nvarchar(max)) as AR_TITRE,
        CAST(A.AR_ARTICLE AS nvarchar(max)) as AR_ARTICLE
    FROM ARTICLE(NOLOCK) A
        INNER JOIN FICHE_IMMOVEIL(NOLOCK) FI ON FI.ID_ARTICLE = A.ID_ARTICLE
    WHERE FI.IM_STATUT = 'LIVR' 
        AND FI.ID_USER <> 'SYS'
)
SELECT
    ID_ARTICLE,
    AR_DT_CREATION,
    AR_TITRE,
    AR_ARTICLE,
    ID_THEME_IMMOVEIL,
    ID_SOUS_THEME_IMMOVEIL
FROM SELECTION_FICHE_IMMOVEIL 
WHERE ID_THEME_IMMOVEIL = 'DC'
ORDER BY IM_DT_CREATION DESC
    OFFSET 0 ROWS
    FETCH FIRST 20000 ROWS ONLY
```

But this one doesn't ? (incorrect syntax near the keyword 'union')

```
WITH SELECTION_FICHE_IMMOVEIL AS 
(
SELECT
        FI.ID_FICHE_IMMOVEIL,
        FI.[ID_THEME_IMMOVEIL ] AS ID_THEME_IMMOVEIL,
        FI.ID_SOUS_THEME_IMMOVEIL,
        FI.IM_DT_CREATION,
        A.ID_ARTICLE,
        A.AR_DT_CREATION,
        CAST(A.AR_TITRE AS nvarchar(max)) as AR_TITRE,
        CAST(A.AR_ARTICLE AS nvarchar(max)) as AR_ARTICLE
    FROM ARTICLE(NOLOCK) A
        INNER JOIN FICHE_IMMOVEIL(NOLOCK) FI ON FI.ID_ARTICLE = A.ID_ARTICLE
    WHERE FI.IM_STATUT = 'LIVR' 
        AND FI.ID_USER <> 'SYS'
)
SELECT
    ID_ARTICLE,
    AR_DT_CREATION,
    AR_TITRE,
    AR_ARTICLE,
    ID_THEME_IMMOVEIL,
    ID_SOUS_THEME_IMMOVEIL
FROM SELECTION_FICHE_IMMOVEIL 
WHERE ID_THEME_IMMOVEIL = 'DC'
ORDER BY IM_DT_CREATION DESC
    OFFSET 0 ROWS
    FETCH FIRST 20000 ROWS ONLY
UNION
SELECT
    ID_ARTICLE,
    AR_DT_CREATION,
    AR_TITRE,
    AR_ARTICLE,
    ID_THEME_IMMOVEIL,
    ID_SOUS_THEME_IMMOVEIL
FROM SELECTION_FICHE_IMMOVEIL 
WHERE ID_THEME_IMMOVEIL = 'RL'
ORDER BY IM_DT_CREATION DESC 
    OFFSET 0 ROWS
    FETCH FIRST 10000 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Can you expand on what "working" and "not working" mean in the context of your queries? If there are errors, please post them. If not, please explain how the output differs from what you expect/desire.

Comment: From SQL Server : 
Msg 156, Niveau 15, État 1, Ligne 29
Syntaxe incorrecte vers le mot clé 'UNION'.

(incorrect syntax near the keyword 'union')

Comment: use  sub queries ....@VincentChalmel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd switch to using `ROW_NUMBER()` instead:

```
WITH SELECTION_FICHE_IMMOVEIL AS 
(
SELECT
        FI.ID_FICHE_IMMOVEIL,
        FI.[ID_THEME_IMMOVEIL ] AS ID_THEME_IMMOVEIL,
        FI.ID_SOUS_THEME_IMMOVEIL,
        FI.IM_DT_CREATION,
        A.ID_ARTICLE,
        A.AR_DT_CREATION,
        CAST(A.AR_TITRE AS nvarchar(max)) as AR_TITRE,
        CAST(A.AR_ARTICLE AS nvarchar(max)) as AR_ARTICLE,

        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FI.[ID_THEME_IMMOVEIL ]
                           ORDER BY FI.IM_DT_CREATION) as rn

    FROM ARTICLE(NOLOCK) A
        INNER JOIN FICHE_IMMOVEIL(NOLOCK) FI ON FI.ID_ARTICLE = A.ID_ARTICLE
    WHERE FI.IM_STATUT = 'LIVR' 
        AND FI.ID_USER <> 'SYS'
)
SELECT
    ID_ARTICLE,
    AR_DT_CREATION,
    AR_TITRE,
    AR_ARTICLE,
    ID_THEME_IMMOVEIL,
    ID_SOUS_THEME_IMMOVEIL
FROM SELECTION_FICHE_IMMOVEIL 
WHERE
   (ID_THEME_IMMOVEIL = 'DC' AND rn <= 20000) OR
   (ID_THEME_IMMOVEIL = 'RL' and rn <= 10000)
ORDER BY IM_DT_CREATION DESC
```

It's probably a bit unhappy about you having `ORDER BY` clauses on both sides of the `UNION` - usually, you need to specify a single `ORDER` that covers the entire combined result set.

In the alternative, you may be able to retain your `UNION` by enclosing the individual queries as subqueries.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is due to having an `ORDER BY` clause against specific queries within your `UNION`. As per [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx):

> **Using UNION of two SELECT statements with ORDER BY**
>
> The order of certain parameters used with the UNION clause is
>   important. The following example shows the incorrect and correct use
>   of UNION in two SELECT statements in which a column is to be renamed
>   in the output.

```
-- Uses AdventureWorks  

IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.Gloves', 'U') IS NOT NULL  
DROP TABLE dbo.Gloves;  
GO  
-- Create Gloves table.  
SELECT ProductModelID, Name  
INTO dbo.Gloves  
FROM Production.ProductModel  
WHERE ProductModelID IN (3, 4);  
GO  

/* INCORRECT */  
-- Uses AdventureWorks  

SELECT ProductModelID, Name  
FROM Production.ProductModel  
WHERE ProductModelID NOT IN (3, 4)  
ORDER BY Name  
UNION  
SELECT ProductModelID, Name  
FROM dbo.Gloves;  
GO  

/* CORRECT */  
-- Uses AdventureWorks  

SELECT ProductModelID, Name  
FROM Production.ProductModel  
WHERE ProductModelID NOT IN (3, 4)  
UNION  
SELECT ProductModelID, Name  
FROM dbo.Gloves  
ORDER BY Name;  
GO
```

Comment: Moving to using a single `ORDER BY` can sometimes make sense, but not here where it's being combined with `FETCH` and `OFFSET` to constraint *how many* rows from each side of the `UNION` are to be included.

Comment: Good answer on WHY there is an error. (Sourcing the doc).
But I will select @Damien_The_Unbeliever since he provides an alternative.

Comment: No problem at all, I agree that Damien's answer resolves your underlying problem more completely.